# Running multiple programs together in the shell script in infinite while loop

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu

I have such a shell script;

```
while true
do
     python get_proxies.py
     python run1.py & python run2.py & python run3.py & python run4.py &
     ......
done
```

In this loop, I want to run such programs together, but I don't want the script to pass to the next loop until all the programs finish processing.

How can I manage that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built in [wait](http://ss64.com/bash/wait.html). So, no need for the loop even:

```
python run1.py & python run2.py & python run3.py & python run4.py &
wait
```

It will wait until the above commands complete

Answer (score 1):

I generally do these using xterm

```
xterm -e "sh -c 'python myscript.py'"
```